# Django 'No such table:" for custom user profile, why?

Tags: django, django-views, django-allauth

I'm tearing my hair out trying to figure out why my custom user profile view no longer works. I'm using django-allauth, and have customised my user profile by creating a model with one-to-one field to the user. However, my view is throwing the error:

```
OperationalError at /profile/

no such table: user_profile

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/profile/
Django Version:     1.7.4
Exception Type:     OperationalError
Exception Value:    

no such table: user_profile

Exception Location:     /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py in execute, line 485
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version:     2.7.6
```

My models.py with the custom user profile looks like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.db import models
from allauth.account.models import EmailAddress


class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile')

    # user visible settings
    stop_reminders = models.BooleanField ( default=False,
                             help_text = 'Flag if user wants reminders not to be sent.' )

    stop_all_email = models.BooleanField ( default=False,
                             help_text = 'Flag if user wants no email to be sent.' )

    # hidden settings
    is_premium =  models.BooleanField ( default=False,
                             help_text = 'Flag if user has the premium service.' )

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "{}'s profile".format(self.user.username)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'user_profile'

    def account_verified(self):
        if self.user.is_authenticated:
            result = EmailAddress.objects.filter(email=self.user.email)
            if len(result):
                return result[0].verified
        return False

#User.profile = property(lambda u: UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=u)[0])

def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
       profile, created = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)

post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User)
```

My view, which is a place to set user profile settings looks like this:

```
@login_required
def user_settings (request):
    """
    User settings view, handles changing of user settings and
    entry distribution (eventually)
    """

    if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...

        form = UserProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user.profile) # A form bound to the POST data

        if form.is_valid(): # All validation rules pass
            form.save ()

            return render_to_response('sm/profile_update_success.html',
                                      {},
                                      context_instance=RequestContext(request))

    else:
        # create unbound form with initial values generated
        # from the user's profile
        form = UserProfileForm (instance=request.user.profile)

    return render ( request, 'profile.html', { 'form': form, } )
```

Until recently this was working fine, and I'm not sure what has changed to make it stop. Can anyone explain please?

I'm using Django-1.7.4 and django-allauth-0.19.1. For debug I'm using sqllite, which I have tried creating using both `python manage.py migrate` and `python manage.py syncdb`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gahh, the answer was that I had commented out my main app's entry from `INSTALLED_APPS`. Which is silly.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, if it worked before, I can't explain why it no longer is.
You should inspect the sqlite file itself, and see if the table is there. (The file is usually found at the root as `db.sqlite3`, and can be opened with any standard sqlite browser)

You mentioned you've been running migrate, but is the actual migration there already?

Run `python manage.py makemigrations` first if you haven't. If need be, verify the migration file itself.

There's also the `python manage.py inspectdb` command that could give you some insight to the models you're using.

If still nothing, you could of course start from scratch. I've probably missed a shortcut somewhere, but I'd:

1. Create a copy of data you do need to keep 
   (`python manage.py dumpdata --indent=4 <appname>`) (Save this into fixtures)
2. delete migrations files
3. delete `db.sqlite3`
4. run `python manage.py makemigrations`
5. run `python manage.py migrate`
6. use `python manage.py loaddata <fixture-name>` to reload old data

Comment: Well, I should say it may have been in an earlier version of Django. If I inspect the database using `python manage.py inspectdb` the `user_profile` table isn't there. Even after deleting the database and running `python manage.py migrate` (I don't care about keeping the old data). So I suppose the real question is, how do I get the table created, and/or why isn't it created?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem but for me the solution was different. I had accidentally deleted the __init__.py file which is required by django in the migrations directory while cleaning which meant that some migrations were not running producing the same error. Replacing it solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. To fix it I exit out of the server by Control+C. Than migrate by running these two commands: $ python manage.py makemigrations
it tells me 
Migrations for 'profiles':

profiles/migrations/0001_initial.py

```
- Create model profile
```

than I run `$ python manage.py migrate`

it tells me

> Operations to perform:   Apply all migrations: admin, auth,
>   contenttypes, profiles, sessions Running migrations:
>
> Applying profiles.0001_initial... OK

now I run the server again $ python manage.py runserver

and when I create the profile it shows

> [24/Aug/2018 19:36:16] "GET /admin/profiles/profile/add/ HTTP/1.1" 200
>   4381
>
> [24/Aug/2018 19:36:19] "POST /admin/profiles/profile/add/ HTTP/1.1"
>   302 0
>
> [24/Aug/2018 19:36:19] "GET /admin/profiles/profile/ HTTP/1.1" 200
>   4376
>
> [24/Aug/2018 19:36:19] "GET /admin/jsi18n/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3217
>
> [24/Aug/2018 19:36:19] "GET /static/admin/css/changelists.css
>   HTTP/1.1" 200 6170
>
> [24/Aug/2018 19:36:19] "GET /static/admin/img/tooltag-add.svg
>   HTTP/1.1" 200 331
>
> [24/Aug/2018 19:36:19] "GET /static/admin/img/icon-yes.svg HTTP/1.1"
>   200 436

and profile is created. Hope that help.

Answer (score 1):

Okay its looks like you forget to run the migrations command; just go ahead and run the following command; in the Django shell:

```
$ python manage.py migrate
```

Then,

```
$ python manage.py makemigrations
```

Answer (score 1):

$ python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb

that's the good way try it